# Cascaded Op-amp circuits

Tags: resistors, amplifier

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Here is good sample [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/63860/solving-this-op-amp-circuit). The user have included his attempts and the experts here gladly to help him out.we would appreciate if you edit your question accordingly. Welcome to Electrical Engineering.SE

Comment: The resistor values for the second stage are given.. so work that part out.  (It seems like you've already written down the equation.)

Answer (score 1):

Start with the 2nd stage because both resistors are specified. Note how much gain that stage has.

Now look at the first stage. The resistor associated with V1 is specified.  So start with V1.  You know what the desired total gain is. Calculate the required gain for the 1st stage. You know what the gain of the 2nd stage is, so this is simple.

Now that you know the required gain for the 1st stage, calculate the feedback resistor needed to achieve that gain.

Finally, calculate the resistor for input V2.  You know the value of the feedback resistor for the 1st stage and you know how much gain the 2nd stage provides, so this is easy as well.